# Why is SSL so special? Can't I just implement RSA on my own?

Tags: encryption, ssl, cryptography, client, security

Instead of spending a bunch of $$ on ssl, can I implement RSA on my own? (I don't care about proving the site's identity; I just want to encrypt a password between clients and the server to protect from man-in-the-middle attacks). I've read that any custom solutions are likely to be very insecure, but could someone read my plan and give a thoughtful response?

First I would create public and private keys. I would encrypt the client password with javascript by translating the letters of the  password to ascii-values, and then multiply or add (any suggestions?) these ascii-values to get the "unencrypted message". I would then encrypt this message using javascript and the public key.

On the server, I would decrypt the secure message using the private key and end up with the sum/product of the password's ascii-values. Any tips on how to get the individual letters from that?

Edit: I've reached the conclusion that SSL is the best way to go. I was only looking at the client to server side of the deal (where all the client sends is a password). Of course, the information sent by the server to the client is valuable, and should not be vulnerable to MITM attacks. Thanks for the free SSL suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: How are you coming to the conclusion that SSL is expensive versus a custom solution?

Comment: There's no need to use RSA for this, you can just use a simple challenge-response protocol in javascript.

Comment: Most of the time, what you pay for the certificate, not the SSL/TLS implementation. If you can't afford a certificate and if your deployment environment is limited, you can use a self-signed cert (or your own CA), as Eugene suggested.

Comment: Practically a duplicate of [How to roll my own security mechanism - avoid SSL](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/9500/2435) (migrated to Security.SE).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a bunch of reasons not to roll your own encryption.

1. SSL gives the user confidence that the site is secure and that eavesdroppers cannot view the password on the wire. If you don't use SSL then the usual browser indications that the site is secure will not be present.
2. It's *really* hard to get RSA right (or any crypto algorithm for that matter). First off, using raw RSA is insecure and you need to have an appropriate padding mechanism and wotnot to make it actually secure. RSA can also only encrypt `n-1` bytes of data, where `n` is the size of the key.
3. Leave crypto to the cryptographers. The first issue with your proposed system is that you're missing the point of using a secure transport: You don't need to do any special encoding of your data (the conversion to ascii and multiplying/summing or whatever part) because the secure transport means that eavesdroppers cannot see what's going past.
4. Your proposal does *not* protect against man-in-the-middle attacks. It (kinda) prevents eavesdropping, which is a different problem.

That said, you certainly can implement RSA in Javascript with a bit of effort, but just be aware that it is unlikely to be secure until you've had a bunch of cryptanalysts look at it and try to break it. You *will* make a mistake somewhere along the line, even if you are the best programmer in the world.

The user experience will also suffer because it will be very hard for the user to verify that they are, in fact, talking to your server.

SSL is a well known, well analysed, not-yet-broken protocol that can be free if you use a self-signed certificate (another poor user experience, but at least it's still fairly secure). Think *very* carefully before you decide to cheap out on the crypto, and make sure you weigh the cost of a certificate against your development time (it'll take you many hours to implement RSA) and the potential cost of leaking important customer information (their password). The cost of the certificate is likely to be insignificant compared to the rest of the project cost.

Comment: Thanks; could you expand on why my proposal protects against eavesdropping vs against man-in-the-middle attacks? I am now convinced to use SSL

Comment: There's nothing in your proposal that prevents an attacker setting up, say, a fake web server with a very similar domain to yours and sending their own public key to the browser. The attacker can then obtain the password and forward the request on to your server so the user doesn't notice. That's a man-in-the-middle attack. Remember that keys don't tell you anything about who owns them, it's the certificates that prove identity.

Comment: @user1114105: Incidentally, this is a great example of what makes crypto so hard: It's really easy to miss some aspect of the problem and wind up with an insecure system. Don't feel bad :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a self-signed certificate on the server and trust it explicitly on the client (i.e. encode certificate parameters etc). So you don't need to reinvent the wheel. I would say more - depending on the library you can use PSK (pre-shared key) cipher suites and get rid of certificates completely.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you need SSL if you cannot afford a certificate.  Obviously, your data you intend to protect does not have much value.

The public/private key system is best way to go.   By the time you figure out how to roll your own and get your CA certificate included in all the major browsers and Operating Systems and become your own Certificate authority, I think you will find spending a few 100$ on cert is cheap.

Comment: Why do you say that the data I'm protecting doesn't have much value because I can't afford a certificate? I am building an admin site for a business, so I do not need to prove to users that my site can be trusted. The data I'm protecting (the business's users passwords) is REALLY valuable!

Comment: Ohhhh now I understand that a man-in-the-middle attack can get information sent from the server to the client and not just the other way around. Protecting it with SSL now sounds much better!

Comment: Just saying that b/c you are looking for a way to avoid spending minimal dollars on a solution that already exists.  If you are doing this for a business - get the SSL cert.  If it was a personal blog, then you'd have to make a call about how important it was.  I cannot tell you how many developers I've had to come behind after they were fired becaused they didn't follow basic security practices.  I had one business customer I helped with a web site accepting credit cards in the clear - developer didn't have a clue.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for SSL but not spending money use www.startssl.com as that will allow you to use SSL free. Creating your own solution will take time and if not done the correct way will be insecure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to implement plain RSA "by hand" in this way. To create the unencrypted message, you can simply use the bits of the message. For example, if your password is `cheese`:

```
c    h    e    e    s    e
0x63 0x68 0x65 0x65 0x73 0x65
```

The number to encrypt could then be simply `0x636865657365`. You'll need to use math routines that can handle large integers (native Javascript numbers aren't big enough).

Standard warnings apply, your solution will have a fatal flaw in some way, etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't care about proving the site's identity; I just want to encrypt a password between clients and the server to protect from man-in-the-middle attacks)

That's exactly why you *do* care about proving the site's identity.

That in turn is why just using RSA without an authentication scheme isn't secure. It's no good having a secret conversation when you can't identify who you're talking to.